# Set image background for view with 3 images sizes

Tags: swift

I did the following:

1) copy 3 images size of wall paper into supporting file folder with standard naming

WP.png, WP@2x.png, WP@3x.png

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "WP"))
}
```

The problems:

1). There are 3 images overlap one another

2) if I did as below, the same problem as (1)

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "WP@2x"))

or

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "WP@2x.png"))

How to make sure the wp size for the right screen size?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the name you provide here (see arrow in image). XCode will add the right image.

[image]

You can also specify the size by hand if you must. This goes as follows:

```
self.yourImageVariableName.size.width = self.frame.size.width
self.yourImageVariableName.size.height = self.frame.size.height
```